# Homeroom name in number

Tags: word-usage

Suppose there are 60 students in the 3rd grade in a primary school. They are divided into three homerooms, normally called Grade 3A, Grade 3B and Grade 3C.
Now here is a case. In a country that does not use Latin alphabet, the students are divided into three homerooms, called Class 1, Class 2 and Class 3. How do you refer it with their year of study when English speaker would understand? Grade 3.1, Grade 3.2 and Grade 3.3?

Comment: Calling the three homerooms grades 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3 sounds like those are advancing levels of the same grade, just like 3.2 is a greater number than 3.1.

Comment: Maybe. I see that in India, they call Grades 3A, 3B and 3C for three homerooms / form classes. But in some counties, such as Japan they call it 3-nen 1-kumi for Grade 3A and 3-nen 2-kumi for Grade 3B. Problem is when I translate a sentence, "3-nen 1-kumi went to a filed trip yesterday", I cannot say Grade 3A, since it changes their class name from 1 to A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty much impossible in general  Most people in the UK won't know what "Grade 3" is in the USA (it is mostly the same as year 4 in England, and Primary 5 in Scotland, but not exactly) Moreover The word "homeroom" would cause mystification in the UK.

If most people are unaware even that there are differences between England, Scotland, and the UK,  they won't know the system in your country, so you will need to explain it to us.

You can just explain the system, exactly as you did in your question and then refer to class 1, class 2 and class 3 of third grade.  It is probably useful to mention the ages of the children, since that universal.

> Pupils aged 8 to 9 are divided into three homerooms called class one, two, and three.

I assume that the other year groups are also divided in a similar way, and perhaps you would have a term in your language like "grade three class one" If so, that is the answer

> There are three homerooms, referred to as grade 3 class 1, 2, and 3.

Don't try to work out what these classes would be called if the school was in the USA.  That is too much of a "counterfactual".

Comment: For homeroom / form class, which translation into English make more sense? Grade 3 Class 1; Year 3 Class 1; Class 1, Grade 3; Class 1, Year 3 (sequence, comma, year/grade)?

Comment: All fine: Perhaps "Year 3, class 1" is simplest, as the most direct translation of the Japanese.